# Show whole text on fixed cursor

Tags: html, css, tooltip, overflow

I have created this `styled-select`, due to my requirements, and it is shown in the example below. Now if the options are longer than the frame, they won't be shown (which is what I require). I want some functionality in order to leave the cursor over any option and the whole text of that option is shown line an `info-box`.
I know that I should use `hover` but I could not remember the name of that functionality.

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reshadgp/qyf22h83/18/)

```js
 $(function() {

   $('.styled-select select').hide();
   $("select#elem").val('0');

   $('.styled-select div').each(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     $(this).html($container.find('select option:selected').text());
   });

   $('.styled-select div').click(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     var opLen = $container.find('select').children('option').length;
     if (opLen < 5) {
       $container.find('select').show().attr('size', opLen).focus();
     } else {
       $container.find('select').show().attr('size', 5).focus();
     }
   });

   $('.styled-select select').click(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     var text = $container.find('select option:selected').text();
     $container.find('div').html(text);
     $container.find('select').hide();
   });

   $('.styled-select select').focusout(function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
     $container.find('select').hide();
   });

 });
```

```css
 .styled-select select {
   position: absolute;
   background: transparent;
   padding-top: 5px;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
   color: black;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 4;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   -o-appearance: none;
   z-index: 1;
   outline: none;
   top: 42px;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
 }
 .styled-select {
   background: url('../img/campaignSelector.png') no-repeat right;
   background-color: white;
   height: 42px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
   background-position: 97% 50%;
 }
 .styled-select option {
   font-size: 18px;
   background-color: white;
   margin-left: 3px;
 }
 .styled-select option:hover {
   //here 

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="styled-select" style="width: 301px; margin:5px 0 0 10px;">
  <div id="userChannelDivId" style="font-size:18px; position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 5px; width: 300px; height: 42px; text-overflow: ellipsis; padding: 0 30px 0 0; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;"></div>
  <select id="userChannelId" name="userChannelId" style="width:100%">
    <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
    <option value="6040224291703">This is a text long enough to go outside frame 01</option>
    <option value="6036780606903">This is a text long enough to go outside frame 02</option>
    <option value="6038009946703">This is a text long enough to go outside frame 03</option>
    <option value="6037196648903">This is a text long enough to go outside frame 04</option>
    <option value="6040601588703">This is a text long enough to go outside frame 05</option>
    <option value="6040080586303">This is a text long enough to go outside frame 06</option>
    <option value="6040602117503">This is a text long enough to go outside frame 07</option>
    <option value="6038006580703">This is a text long enough to go outside frame 08</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

I can not use `title` because these options are generated by getting data from database as follow:

```
<form:select id="campaignGoalId" path="campaignStructureList[${status1.index}].dataSourceModelList[${status2.index}].goalId" style="position: absolute;">
    <form:option value="" label="--- Select ---" />
    <form:options  items="${campaignConfigurationModel.gaGoalList}" itemValue="goalId" itemLabel="goalIdName" />
</form:select>
```

Comment: Are you looking for tooltip ?

Comment: @Akshay exactly ! I did not remember tooltip ;) Thanks

Comment: But how can I use tooltip in order to show the options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use the title attribute ?

`<option title="This is a text long enough to go outside frame 08">`

This is probably the easiest way.

Comment: because these options are not fixed, and they will be filled by getting data from database.

Comment: But you will still be populating those on the option in order to show them on the ui right? You can use the same logic for the title attribute as well.

Comment: unfortunately did not work, Cause I have <options> as I added to update part.

Comment: Umm. There is another way. You can add the title attribute dynamically after DOM has loaded.   $('select option').each(function() {$(this).attr('title',$(this).text())};                                                                            Something like this.